# Wireguard connection doesnt work after reboot

Tags: reboot, wireguard

After reboot of ubuntu client, "server" wireguard tunnel cannot ping client. Connection establishes only after i manually ping host through tunnel from client.

---

My config

Server: Mikrotik 7.11 (stable)

Client: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Client behind router with NAT, with forward all needable ports

---

Output of `wg show`:

```
interface: wg0
  public key: <public_key_of_client>
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51821

peer: <public_key_of_server>
  endpoint: <IP>:51821
  allowed ips: 10.0.1.1/32
  persistent keepalive: every 5 seconds
```

---

What I already checked:

1. MTU on both peers same
2. All keys are correct (otherwise ping won't work)
3. KeepPersistentalive on client set to 5
4. Client don't even to try send handshakes
5. wg-quick service setups only after internet device is plugged
6. Time on server and client are the same